# How to use passwords with Hapi/Glue/Compose?

Tags: hapi.js

I have a project which configures a Hapi web server via [glue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glue) and [compose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/confidence).

Excerpt from TypeScript file:

```
import { compose as glue } from 'glue';
import { Store } from 'confidence';
import config from './config.json';

const manifest = new Store(config).get('/', {
  env: process.env.NODE_ENV,
});
const options = {
  relativeTo: __dirname,
};
const server = await glue(manifest, options);
```

**The problem now is that all passwords are directly stored in the *config.json* file.**

Does *confidence* support the injection of passwords, for example from environment variables?

Or do I somehow have to inject them afterwards, for example using [nconf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nconf)?

Answer (score 0):

I thought same and added my small modification to manifest file. You can use external config library. I am using [node-config](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config).
Now I can separate my development and production passwords/keys/secrets. 
To `.gitignore` file I added

```
config/development.json
config/test.json
config/production.json
```

Local development uses development.json and production uses production.json. This way I don't need to put my secrets to a file and push to the repo.

[Here](https://github.com/metoikos/hapi-moon/blob/master/config/manifest.js) you can find implementation details. It will give you an idea of how this works.